# Unable to login with YouTrack Integration in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, youtrack

How can I "debug" how why I can't login with the YouTrack integration plugin with IntelliJ?

I've set the following:

```
Server: https://mycompany.myjetbrains.com/ 
Username: My_Name
*(Taken from https://mycompany.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/admin/hub/users/My_Name?tab=general, I also tried my email address as username)*
Password: perm:*** (the permanent token generated from the dashboard)
```

But it just keeps on throwing the same "Unable to login" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure to spell the server URL in full, as seen in the browser address bar: `https://mycompany.myjetbrains.com/youtrack`

I'd also recommend trying https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/YouTrack-Integration-Plugin.html#youtrack-integration-ide-plugin instead, as it has more features and can handle cases like that on its own.